# How to determine the collation of a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, collation, ddl, dml

I want to script a check of the collations used on my tables in PostgreSQL, but googling for `Postgresql detect collation` is not working well for me, and the documentation is not making this an easy search.

Can anyone tell me how I would check this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To check for non-default collations on columns, you can use the following query:

```
select table_schema, 
       table_name, 
       column_name,
       collation_name
from information_schema.columns
where collation_name is not null
order by table_schema,
         table_name,
         ordinal_position;
```

To find the collation of the database, you need to query `pg_database`:

```
select datname, 
       datcollate
from pg_database;
```

Here are the relevant pages of the PostgreSQL manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-collations.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html

Answer (score 8):

In addition to a_horse_with_no_name's answer, if you want the collation for the database you're currently connected to, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT datcollate AS collation
FROM pg_database 
WHERE datname = current_database();
```